# How asyncio understands that task is complete for non-blocking operations

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm trying to understand how asyncio works. As for I/O operation i got understand that when await was called, we register Future object in EventLoop, and then calling epoll for get sockets which belongs to Future objects, that ready for give us data. After we run registred callback and resume function execution.

But, the thing that i cant understant, what's happening if we use await not for I/O operation. How eventloop understands that task is complete?  Is it create socket for that or use another kind of loop? Is it use epoll? Or doesnt it add to Loop and used it as generator?

There is an example:

```
import asyncio

async def test():
    return 10



async def my_coro(delay):
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    end_time = loop.time() + delay
    while True:
        print("Blocking...")
        await test()
        if loop.time() > end_time:
            print("Done.")
            break
async def main():
    await my_coro(3.0)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`await` doesn't automatically yield to the event loop, that happens only when an async function (anywhere in the chain of awaits) requests suspension, typically due to IO or timeout not being ready.

In your example the event loop is never returned to, which you can easily verify by moving the "Blocking" print before the `while` loop and changing `main` to `await asyncio.gather(my_coro(3.0), my_coro(3.0))`. What you'll observe is that the coroutines are executed in series ("blocking" followed by "done", all repeated twice), not in parallel ("blocking" followed by another "blocking" and then twice "done"). The reason for that was that there was simply no opportunity for a context switch - `my_coro` executed in one go as if they were an ordinary function because none of its awaits ever chose to suspend.